# Does Serpent/Solidity allow functions to jump into other functions?

Tags: solidity, evm, serpent

Do either Serpent or Solidity allow calling other functions in the same contract via a `JUMP` opcode, or do they only use `CALL`?

Answer (score 1):

All function calls within the same contract (except those explicitly marked `external`) are implemented as JUMPs in Solidity by default.

Comment: I ask because I believe Serpent always uses `CALL`